# what is time complexity and space complexity

Tags: algorithm

I am very confused about the time complexity and space complexity, I know for loop is O(N) and for loop inside for loop is O(N), I really don't understand when I have a algorithm, how to check it's time complexity and space complexity in the first place, is there any way to do it ? I have a code following , could you guys help me how to figure out it's time and space complexity, thank you so much!

```
**public void deleteNode(ListNode node) {
        if(node == null)
            return;
        if(node.next == null){
            node = null;
            return;
        }
        node.val = node.next.val;
        node.next = node.next.next;
    }**
```

Comment: The time complexity might be that you have to calculate each cycle of CPU so that you know how many cycles total operations need

Comment: As for your code, it runs in constant time, so `O(1)` since nothing in that function depends on a variable size (of the list for example).

Comment: O(1) is time complexity  or space complexity ?